# Why are "media types" in media queries used?

Tags: css, media-queries

I keep seeing tons of examples of media queries that look like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape)
```

or

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

Now, I understand HOW keywords like "screen" and "print" and "speech" are used, but I don't get the point. Maybe using "print" for some changes to save ink (though I imagine that's an edge case since backgrounds don't print by default), but why would you ever need to specify "speech"? Why do  examples of media queries so often specify "screen"?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @eriyu remember to accept the naswer if it helped you , some one answered verry clear down there

Comment: @JeffersonXMasonic It actually doesn't answer my question at all. I'm asking why you would NEED to specify, like in what situation would you need to serve different CSS to someone using a screenreader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#intro) from W3C suggest that media queries could also be used for HTML, XHTML, XML. Perhaps, queries with speech media type were mainly used for importing text to speech software into varieties of document types.

This is the only [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/#background) that I could find describing the speech media type But it does not really provide a great example of how it is used.

As for why the examples often used screen media type, simply because it is the most often used. Previous versions of media queries had many media types, but are now removed as they have few uses or serve the same purpose with the current media types.

In the future, they may alter their specification, removing those not very useful media types or adding more of it to suit future technologies.

Update: I found a [GitHub thread](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1751) discussing about speech media type. It basically says that speech is mainly for user agent that deals with speech. E.g. Siri or Alexa.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Syntax

```
@media not|only mediatype and (media feature and|or|not mediafeature) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

meaning of the not, only and and keywords:

`not`: The not keyword reverts the meaning of an entire media query.

`only`: The only keyword prevents older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles. It has no effect on modern browsers.

`and`: The and keyword combines a media feature with a media type or other media features.

They are all optional. However, if you use not or only, you must also specify a media type.

Media Types

**all**  Default. Used for all media type devices

**print**   Used for printers

**screen**  Used for computer screens, tablets, smart-phones etc.

**speech**  Used for screenreaders that "reads" the page out loud